# Internet Explorer not setting <img> src precisely, converting %7E to ~

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, amazon-s3

Through JS I am trying to set the src attribute of an <img> tag.

I'm setting it to the URL of a file that's on Amazon, but if this file has a tilde in its name, Amazon expects %7E. IE changes this to a tilde, while FF keeps it as the escape code. So I'm telling the browser to set the src to, say, 'http://s3.amazon.com/bucket/file%7E1.png', but in IE it unescapes it back to 'http://s3.amazon.com/bucket/file~1.png'

I figured out that it was converting it by using jQuery( 'img' )[index].src. This confirmed that IE was changing %7E back to ~. This is breaking my code because Amazon does not expect the file to be requested this way.

This is happening on IE 9, in all three modes (IE7 mode, IE8 mode, IE9 mode).

I've tried double-escaping (using %257E, as %25 is the code for %), but IE doesn't change %25 to %.

Anyone have experience with IE changing your data like this?

---

EDIT: I tried using $( 'img' ).attr(), but the bug still happens.

Here's an easy way to show the problem I'm having. Copy this to an HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<img src="blank" />
Don't worry about the broken image
```

(you may have to tell IE to allow the cross-site JS request)

Then open up the IE Javascript console and run

```
$( 'img' )[0].src = 'http://s3.amazon.com/bucket/file%7E1.png';
```

Then run

```
$( 'img' )[0].src
```

What I'm getting is "http://s3.amazon.com/bucket/file~1.png". IE is doing some post processing here for some reason, and I want to get around it so the src points to the right place.

Thanks for the help so far guys!

---

Another edit.

Some more context: I am trying to display dynamic files that a user has uploaded to S3, so changing the file name is not an option.

Comment: How did you check it? I'm unable to reproduce it - everything stays 'as is' in IE and other browsers. Are you talking about this example? http://jsfiddle.net/KnTHN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Like Cheery, I couldn't reproduce it either. But I would suggest you use jquery's .attr method. Like this:

`jQuery('img').attr('src', url);`

Note that you may need to change the selector if you want to hit a specific img index.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `%` if you need it verbatim: `%257E`

Comment: Tried that - IE doesn't change %25 to %; for some reason it stays the same. %7E to ~ is a different story, though.

Comment: I swear on my mother's grave!

Comment: @S-OBrien: I'm sure she didn't raise you to swear!